# Alignment problem in 2 vector shapefiles with the same projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, modis, alignment

I have 2 vector shapefiles of Manila that are supposed to align, but they do not (screenshot attached). I have projected them to the same projection (World Mercator WGS 84, EPSG 3395). One shapefile appears to be shifted to the right and does not align with the Google Street basemap and the other shapefile. I am using QGIS 2.14.16.

The pixelised shapefile in the picture was actually from a MODIS 500m raster image which I polygonised. The other shapefile is the administrative outline of Manila, from GADM.

I understand that MODIS data may have some misalignment issues that may be the cause of this problem, which I have not seen in other forums.

Any ideas as to what could be the problem and solution?

[image]

---

Tried to change the shapefiles to EPSG 3857 to match Google Street's projection as suggested by AndreJ. Unfortunately both shapefiles are more misaligned.
[image]

Comment: Google basemap should be EPSG:3875. 3395 might lead to wrong results. What was the original CRS of the shifted layer?

Comment: Thanks for your input! Tried to change both shapefiles to EPSG 3875. Both shapefiles are now even more misaligned unfortunately. Will upload a screenshot to my original question.

Comment: The original CRS of the shifted layer is Geog WGS 84.

Comment: If you did `Set CRS for Layer`, that was wrong. set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3875, and take the shapefiles with their original CRS. Can you link to the MODIS file download site? Does the raster align with the GADM shapefile?

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152663/projected-modis-data-not-aligning-with-esri-basemap-in-arcgis-for-desktop?rq=1 There might be something wrong in the conversion from MODIS to shapefile, regarding sphere vs ellipsoid.

Comment: Note: 3857, not 3875.EPSG::3875 does exist---for use in Finland.

Comment: Thanks @AndreJ and mkennedy. I set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857 as you suggested. It still doesn't work. Here's the link to the MODIS data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B2CeJS8C398Ma3pZMHVfSkZCUW8?usp=sharing

Comment: Also- in a guideline document about MODIS data, this is noted: "In ArcGIS, this dataset will open with the default coordinate system WGS 1984. For correct alignment, the projection information should be set to the geographic coordinate system Clarke 1866 authalic sphere (under spheroid)." I'm using QGIS, so I tried reprojecting the data to EPSG:4052 based on this recommendation. Still does not align.

Comment: In this case, you **have** to use `Set CRS for Layer`- but the download you provide is alredy clipped, so you might have to set the CRS before that. The doc under https://nelson.wisc.edu/sage/data-and-models/readme_modis500m_global_urban_map2014.doc mentions a sinusoidal dataset as well, maybe this fits better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alignment error must be somewhere in the preprocessing of the data.

You can find MODIS land cover data for Manila at ftp://ftp.glcf.umd.edu/glcf/Global_LNDCVR/UMD_TILES/Version_5.1/2012.01.01/MCD12Q1_V51_LC1.2012.PN5152/

and it fits quite good to an Openstreetmap background:

[image]